# SQL query - Join two tables bringing back only lowest price from table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two MSSQL tables as follows:

```
boat_data

boat_prices
```

Boat data houses rows of data about boats. Each boat has a unique ID (pricingRef)
Boat prices houses rows of rental prices for each boat and can have any number of rows for each boat. Each row also has a pricingRef value. Example data in the boat_prices table might be:

```
pricingRef > pricingDescription > price

ASD1 > fullDay > 1500

ASD1 > perWeek > 9000

ASD1 > morning > 800

ASD2 > fullDay > 2000

ASD2 > perWeek > 12000

ASD2 > morning > 1100
```

What I need to do is bring back all rows from the boat_data table and join it to the boat_prices table bringing back only the lowest price for each boat. I've written the SQL statement below which works. The problem is it's really clunky and messy. I've used min(price) to bring back the price value from the boat_prices table and then explicitly requested each field from the boat_data table and then grouped by every field in the boat_data table.

There must be a better way of achieving this. Apologies I'm a SQL novice. Please help!

```
select 
min(price) as price,
boat_data.ID,
boat_data.boatRef,
boat_data.capacity,
boat_data.sleeps,
boat_data.fuelConsumption,
boat_data.yearBuilt,
boat_data.length,
boat_data.beam,
boat_data.engines,
boat_data.tender,
boat_data.boatName,
boat_data.cabins,
boat_data.speed,
boat_data.location,
boat_data.onSale,
boat_data.supplierID,
boat_data.boatClassID,
boat_data.pricingRef,
boat_data.crew,
boat_data.sportsEquipment 
from boat_data 
join boat_prices 
     on boat_data.pricingRef = boat_prices.pricingRef 
group by 
boat_data.ID,
boat_data.boatRef,
boat_data.capacity,
boat_data.sleeps,
boat_data.fuelConsumption,
boat_data.yearBuilt,
boat_data.length,
boat_data.beam,
boat_data.engines,
boat_data.tender,
boat_data.boatName,
boat_data.cabins,
boat_data.speed,
boat_data.location,
boat_data.onSale,
boat_data.supplierID,
boat_data.boatClassID,
boat_data.pricingRef,
boat_data.crew,
boat_data.sportsEquipment 
order by price
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this:

```
select boat_data.*,
       t.min_price
from boat_data
  join (
     select pricingref, min(price) as min_price
     from boat_prices
     group by pricingref
  ) t on t.pricingref = boat_data.pricingref;
```

Comment: in this case he will get only prices in "mornings" cause they are lowest, well he said lowest

Comment: @mirkobrankovic: that's what Jason asked for: "*bringing back only the lowest price for each boat*".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
SELECT bp.price,
       bd.*
FROM boat_data bd
JOIN boat_prices bp ON bd.pricingRef = bp.pricingRef
WHERE bp.price = (SELECT MIN(bp2.price)
                  FROM boat_prices bp2
                  WHERE bp2.pricingRef = bd.pricingRef)
ORDER BY bp.price
```